# Extract single and double quotes urls from link using regex

Tags: php, regex, url, href, quoting

I need to extract Twitter ids for a PHP script using regex. It works great as long as the URLs is coded with double quotes...

```
<a href='http://www.twitter.com/singlequotes'>Twitter Single Quotes</a>
<a href="http://www.twitter.com/doublequotes">Twitter Double Quotes</a>

// regular expression
/<a [^>]*\bhref\s*=\s*"\K[^"]*twitter.com[^"]*/
```

I have tried using `"|'`, `["']`and many other things, that are not working. Would be very thankful, if you could help me with this. Thanks!

https://regex101.com/r/7Zu3uF/1

Comment: But then you have also to add the apex in `[^"]`, see https://regex101.com/r/7Zu3uF/2

Comment: This is  great, but using this expression in my `preg_match_all("/<a [^>]*\bhref\s*=\s*['"]\K[^'"]*twitter.com[^'"]*/g", $result, $results);
` results in a `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '"]\K[^'"' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING) in...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is as fast as you can go.  No capture group is needed.

`href=['"]\K[^'"]+`

[Pattern Demo](https://regex101.com/r/7Zu3uF/3)

Look for a single or double quote after `href=` then match everything that isn't a single or double quote.  That is as simple as it can be made.

p.s. If you are concerned with spaces near the `=` then use:

`href *= *['"]\K[^'"]+`

PHP Implementation ([PHP Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/6ef9366963411e4b334cd161270901f04bf82c81)):

```
$in='<a href=\'http://www.twitter.com/singlequotes\'>Twitter Single Quotes</a>
<a href="http://www.facebook.com/doublequotes">Twitter Double Quotes</a>
<a href=\'http://twitter.com/singlequotes\'>Twitter Single Quotes</a>
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/doublequotes">Twitter Double Quotes</a>';

$companies=['twitter','facebook'];

$out=preg_match_all('/href *= *[\'"]\Khttps?:\/\/(?:www\.)?(?:'.implode('|',$companies).')\.com[^\'"]+/',$in,$out)?$out[0]:[];

var_export($out);
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your support. But my problem is, that I need to define specific URLs inside my pattern. In this case, twitter.com, could be facebok.com... How would the pattern look like for those cases?

Comment: Thanks. But `preg_match_all("/href=['"]\Khttps?:\/\/www\.(?:twitter|facebook)\.com[^'"]+/g", $result, $results);`does also result in a **parse error** in my PHP code. :( Have no idea how to solve this. Regex works great though.

Comment: Awesome, thanks! I tried, but didn't get the solution for this problem: how can I wildcard everything between `href="`and `anything.com` as I do not get any results for `href="https://twitter.com...`for example... Thanks!

Comment: This is awesome! Thank you so much! Just to make sure I don't bother you in the future: if I want to exclude URLs containing a specific character like `?`, how can I define this in my regex?

Comment: @vloryan First of all, you can bother me anytime.  I volunteer my time here because I want to help people.  Second, are you asking about excluding the entire query string of the url?  or are you asking about denying entire urls that have a query string?

Comment: There should be no regex match as soon as this character is included. Ignore it, search for the next match.

Comment: @vloryan Here is the latest pattern for you.  [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/7Zu3uF/4)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145268/discussion-between-vloryan-and-mickmackusa).